# Azure Deploy Service Fabric Application error: no

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to deploy a Service Fabric app from TFS online builds.  I added a **Deploy Service Fabric** and made the following settings (seem to be the recommended settings everywhere):

Application Package:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/drop/applicationpackage
```

Publish Profile:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/drop/projectartifacts/**/PublishProfiles/Dev.xml
```

Then when I run the build, I get the error:

```
Searching for path: 

d:\_work\16\s\**\drop\projectartifacts\**\PublishProfiles\Dev.xml
No items were found with search pattern d:\_work\16\s\**\drop\projectartifacts\**\PublishProfiles\Dev.xml.
Searching for path: d:\_work\16\s\**\drop\applicationpackage

No items were found with search pattern d:\_work\16\s\**\drop\applicationpackage
```

Any idea what I am missing?  I am new to this, if you need more information, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: What's the structure of your project? (Dev.xml and applicationpackage path) You can provide the screenshot here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration?  Specifically, the instructions for how to setup a build definition?  The build definition that you create needs to place the necessary files in the drop location that you are referencing here in your configuration of the Deploy task.

Comment: Excellent!  This got me further, but I hit another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936932/azure-tfs-service-fabric-release-exception-calling-ctor-with-1-arguments

Comment: @naspinski can you please explain what you did to solve your issue? E.g., did you have to change something in the build definition or the release definition?