# VSTS Service Fabric Release to Azure: Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: authority"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, release, azure-service-fabric

Following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration

But when I run the actual deploy, I get the following constructor error which is not very helpful.

```
==============================================================================
Task         : Service Fabric Application Deployment
Description  : Deploy a Service Fabric application to a cluster.
Version      : 1.1.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=820528)
==============================================================================
Searching for path: C:\a\r1\a\LONG_PATH\PublishProfiles\Dev.xml
Found path: C:\a\r1\a\LONG_PATH\PublishProfiles\Dev.xml
Searching for path: C:\a\r1\a\**\drop\applicationpackage
Found path: C:\a\r1\a\PATH\drop\applicationpackage
AAD Authority: 
Cluster Application ID: 
Client Application ID: 
##[error]Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: authority"
##[section]Finishing: Deploy Service Fabric Application
##[section]Finishing: Release
```

Any ideas?  Where can I look for possibly a better error message?  If I deploy from my desktop and VS2015 it works fine.  Thank you.

**IN REPLY TO MATT THALMAN:**

```
ConnectionEndpoint   : {myapp.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000}
FabricClientSettings : {
                       ClientFriendlyName                   : PowerShell-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
                       PartitionLocationCacheLimit          : 100000
                       PartitionLocationCacheBucketCount    : 1024
                       ServiceChangePollInterval            : 00:02:00
                       ConnectionInitializationTimeout      : 00:00:02
                       KeepAliveInterval                    : 00:00:20
                       HealthOperationTimeout               : 00:02:00
                       HealthReportSendInterval             : 00:00:00
                       HealthReportRetrySendInterval        : 00:00:30
                       NotificationGatewayConnectionTimeout : 00:00:30
                       NotificationCacheUpdateTimeout       : 00:00:30
                       AuthTokenBufferSize                  : 4096
                       }
```

Comment: Very strange.  It looks like the metadata being returned from the cluster is not set based on the empty values for the authority and app IDs.  From your local machine, try running the following PowerShell: Connect-ServiceFabricCluster <cluster_endpoint> -AzureActiveDirectory -ServerCertThumbprint <thumbprint> -GetMetadata.  You'll be prompted to input your credentials.  Use the same credentials that you configured when defining your cluster endpoint in VSTS.  Does it show an AzureActiveDirectoryMetadata property in the output? Are the authority and app IDs missing there as well?

Comment: added the metadata that came back to my description

Comment: Are you sure you specified the -GetMetadata parameter in the command?  Can you include both the command you executed as well as the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the feedback of [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3183) issue, you can track it, based on that feedback, the workaround is using certificate authentication.

On the other hand, you can check the source code of that task from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/ServiceFabricDeploy).

Answer (score 1):

I've got this issue when I try execute powershell without quotes ("").
Visual Studio during deploy in first time generate powershell script, which use for deploy. Try execute this script manually, and you will see which arguments put in parameters without quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the input - any idea on how I can extract the script from this tool?